# CNContact: Add new contact during selection?

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm wondering how you would add new contacts during a contact selection using the new CNContacts framework in iOS with Swift?

Currently I'm using the CNContactPickerViewController to let the user choose from the currently stored contacts in the addressbook.

What's bugging me is, that there is no possibility to add a new contact if it is not yet present - so the user has to abort the selection process, swap to the contacts app, add a new contact, and try to select it again in my app.

How to use the new CNContacts framework, allowing adding new contacts from within the contacts selection? Just where the user notices, the contact is not yet available?

I believe this should be possible somehow without programming fully custom view controllers?

I've tried to subclass CNContactPickerViewController and customize the tabBarItems - but this does not seem to have any effect:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(.Add, target: self, selector: "add:")
}

func add(sender: AnyObject){
    print("add new contact")
}
```